# Not able to run ansible playbook in ec2(host machine) to Mac(target machine)

Tags: linux, macos, amazon-ec2, ansible

My mac machine is communicating with an ec2 instance, SSH connection is established and when it's pinged ,I am getting a response as "pong", but when I run playbook facing below issue.

but when I run playbook getting below error:

```
PLAY [macserver] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [X.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
X.X.X.X : ok=0 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

running the playbook as ec2-user, also just to check if issue is with ec2-user added new user as "ansible" in my linux ec2 instance and started running playbook, but still same issue is persisting.
Also I have added ec2-user in sudoers file.

I tried alternative method to run playbook as specified below:

`"ansible-playbook paybook.yml -k -K"`

command to give password and run playbook,
in that scenario facing incorrect sudo password error. Whereas the password created for root, ec2-user and ansible all are same. 
I am not able to figure out what and where I am missing, Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You are connecting your Mac from EC2. "Missing sudo password" is not of root/ec2-user of EC2 server but of the Mac. You need to provide username/password/sudo access etc of target machine.

Comment: @saurabh14292 thanks this worked.. Also for others info: SSH password= host machine pw, become password=target machine password. 
few more questions,
1. does user matter???? one of my co-worker told need to use different user other than ec2-user? can I continue in ec2-user?
2.Consider if i have 5 target machines and all those machines have different password... what can we do in that scenario????

Comment: Added comment and about ec2-user as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connecting your Mac from EC2. "Missing sudo password" is not of root/ec2-user of EC2 server but of the Mac. You need to provide username/password/sudo access etc of target machine

Regarding use of "ec2-user".
You can continue with ec2-user or ubuntu user, which is a default user for EC2 instance. However, it is always a good practice to create a new user(s) with restricted accesses and delete the default user.

Comment: so what about my 2nd question? What if we have different target machines with different passowrd? how can we connect during that time? Also can this be avoided?

Comment: Yes, ideally, you should group the servers according to say, their usage or their configuration etc. Every group of servers can have different user, password etc. Use "Group vars" for that. Refer https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#group-variables

Comment: how can I avoid that step... everytime I need to give password to run a playbook? any alternative?

Comment: No. The group vars are part of your inventory file. Read more on the reference link I have provided above.